# Как насчет оповещений о вероятном спаме в нашем уютном чатике?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, чат, спам

Есть такая штука - [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector). Это программа, которая анализирует весь публикуемый контент и оповещает о вероятном спаме в определённые чаты ([полный список](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki/Chat-Rooms)).

Предлагаю направить [выдачу *по ru.SO*](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=&why=&site=281&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) в наш уютный чатик. Будем справляться со спамом ещё быстрее.

Некоторый минус в том, что в чатике будут лишние сообщения.

Пример здесь: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq

---

UPD:

- https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/commit/0ac9fd6
- https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki/Chat-Rooms

Comment: Насколько это реально проблема? Разве спама так много, что нужны боты? По-моему, это инструмент для модераторов, соответственно, можно создать отдельный чат для этих уведомлений.

Comment: @Squidward в чате Charcoal-HQ модераторов меньшинство (если вообще есть), но тамошние участники отбивают подавляющее большинство спама на SE. Не понимаю, зачем оставлять это модераторам, если все могут принимать участие.

Comment: Для контекста, список недавних оповещений с этого сайта: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=&why=&site=281&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search

Comment: @ᴡᴏʀᴅs вы каждый раз под новым именем, не узнать. )

Comment: Судя по графику, сейчас произошёл скачок активности спама и получается порядка одного сообщения за 8 часов. Не думаю, что это приведёт к захвату чата роботизированными бандформированиями (бот-локализатор периодически заваливает чат здоровенными списками, и ничего, живём).

Comment: @D-side Если честно, не знаю, зачем этот спам от бота-локализатора. Интересно это очень малому числу народа.