# С какой целью был введен лимит в 50 баллов репутации для возможности комментировать?

Tags: обсуждение

**Первый пример:**

[Как обработать массив быстро параллельными вычислениями?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575710/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Pavel Mayorov в комментарии попросил уточнить технические подробности. ТС не смог дать комментарий, и видимо по этой причине создал другой аккаунт, но с него - опять не смог прокомментировать. Тогда ТС начал комментировать в ответах на вопрос, а т.к. ответы постоянно меняют свою позицию - логика теряется.

**Второй пример:**

[Подходит ли MSMQ в качестве замены TcpClient\SslStream?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575017/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-msmq-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-tcpclient-sslstream)

Меня заинтересовал ответ на данный вопрос, я назначил за него конкурс из своей репутации, и, незная особенностей - не оставил себе приемлемого лимита репутации. Теперь и я лишился возможности комментировать.

**Вопрос:** кто придумал этот лимит, с какой целью, будет ли этот лимит снят? Получается что вопросы может задавать кто угодно, даже анонимные пользователи, а комментировать без 50 баллов репутации - нельзя!

Comment: Лимит в 50 баллов не учитывается при комментировании собственных вопросов, насколько я знаю. Так что первый пример - мимо.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну не совсем мимо. У многих пользователей несколько устройств, и многие не всегда помнят пароли. Поэтому на каждом последующем устройстве - заводят новый аккаунт. Но в целом Вы конечно правы.

Comment: тут в движке есть какая-то проблема с регистрацией анонимов. некоторые пользователи не подхватываются после регистрации - именно это произошло в первом примере. в таких случаях стоит ставить тревоги для модераторов с просьбой слить аккаунты.

Comment: @PashaPash, так проблема с регистрацией анонимов ясная. Нет обязательного подтверждения e-mail адреса перед постингом вопроса. Можно вбить любой, даже несуществующий e-mail и задать вопрос. Одна ошибка в адресе - и аккаунт уже не ваш.

Comment: @Align: Насчёт репутации не волнуйтесь, 31 балл по идее несложно набрать за день-два. Это всего 1-2 нетривиальных ответа.

Comment: @Align `Одна ошибка в адресе - и аккаунт уже не ваш.` – кроме адреса, есть и другие индикаторы. В любом случае объединяет аккаунты человек, которому можно объяснить ситуацию. Довольно часто мы просто замечаем такие дублированные учётки и просим Николаса объединить их. Вчера только про два случая ему писал.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Это нужно для защиты от спама

В данный момент только что зарегистрировавшийся пользователь, имеющий 1 балл репутации, может только задать вопрос или дать ответ на существующий вопрос. То и другое

1. Попадает в очередь проверок новых сообщений,
2. Появляется в топе активных вопросов,
3. Проверяется [SmokeDetector](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3467/181472).

Благодаря этому, свежим вопросам и ответам, особенно от новых пользователей, уделяется достаточно внимания, чтобы распознать спам. Кроме того, система не позволяет задавать вопросы слишком часто, а если одно из сообщений пользователя было удалено как спам, то вовсе блокирует возможность что-либо публиковать с конкретного IP на пару дней.

Комментарии гораздо сложнее проверять. Если открыть возможность комментировать для новых пользователей, спамеры сразу этим воспользуются.

> будет ли этот лимит снят?

Нет, наверняка не будет. Как уже отметил PashaPash, для собственных вопросов и ответов этот лимит не действует.

#### Проще набрать 50 репутации

Это можно воспринимать как тест Тьюринга. Если новый участник - не бездушная спам-машина, то первые два-три нормальных вопроса или ответа позволяют преодолеть барьер.

Поскольку в данной ситуации у вас возникли затруднения из-за непонимания механизмов сайта (не всегда очевидных), думаю что конкурс можно отменить и вернуть вам репутацию. Если хотите это сделать, оставьте тревогу "требуется вмешательство модератора" на конкурсном вопросе и кратко опишите ситуацию. Потом вы сможете повторно объявить конкурс, но с другим размером награды.

#### Учётные записи можно (и нужно) объединять

> Можно вбить любой, даже несуществующий e-mail и задать вопрос. Одна ошибка в адресе - и аккаунт уже не ваш

Пока вы ещё залогинены на устройстве, с него можно отправить заявку на объединение с другой учетной записью.

Comment: про "тест Тьюринга" не стоит забывать, что медиана репутации на SO равна `1`. Если использовать метрику: опубликовал >=5 сообщений, то это небольшая доля посетителей SO (хотя относительно других технических сайтов, я думаю, SO очень хорошо выглядит, к примеру, не хуже wikipedia).

Comment: SO на русском имеет меньше [400 участников, которые 5 вопросов/ответов (незаминусованных, закрытых, удалённых) в последний месяц опубликовали](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/391011/monthly-active-users-in-stackoverflow-stackexchange)

Answer (score 17):

В дополнение к [ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3876/6) [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin).

Когда участник регистрируется в системе, с большой вероятностью, он не знает как она работает. Если участнику сразу будет доступен весь функционал, может быть допущена ошибка.

Stack Overflow – сложная система базирующаяся на идеологии создаваемой сообществом годами. Чтобы понять как все устроено, необходимо использовать систему какое-то время. Репутация, в конечном итоге, будет означать, что участник разобрался в устройстве сайта и его идеологии, и может без каких-либо преград использовать весь функционал.